# how to multiply the two numbers in datagridview

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I want to multiply two numbers one by one until last row in datagridview; and add them in a double variable .

They then divided by the total units do.

For example:

```
  mark |units |result
  12.00 * 2   = 24.00
  20.00 * 3   = 60.00
  15.00 * 1   = 15.00



24 + 60 + 15 = 59
59 / 2 + 3 + 1
= 59 /6
= 16.50
```

so show in a textbox.

```
       for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount ; i++)
       {<br>
             mark = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);<br>
             unit = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);<br>
             sumunit += unit;<br>
            result += ( mark * unit);<br>

       }<br>
       result /= sumunit;<br>
       label2.Text = result.ToString();<br>

    }<br>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do it in `DataGrid`, but do it directly in the data you bind to.

Ad new row were result of computation are stored, and *after* bind it to `DataGrid`.